# Thymeleaf form handling returning Null?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, forms, thymeleaf

I've been trying to create form handling using Thymeleaf in Springboot and have been running into an error where it is returning Null to controller.

HTML Table Code:

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th::object="${status}" method="post">
                            <input type="text" th:field="*{stat}"/>
                            <br>
                            <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
                        </form>
```

Object Code:

```
public class status {
    private String stat;

    public String getStat() {
        return stat;
    }

    public void setStat(String stat) {
        System.out.println(stat);
        this.stat = stat;
    }
}
```

Controller Code:

```
 @GetMapping("/")
    public String home(Model model ) {
        model.addAttribute("stat", new status());
        databaseConn objA = new databaseConn ( );
        try{
            model.addAttribute("alert", objA.datacon());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        System.out.println("Test");
        // use alerts.html as template
        return "alerts";
    }
    @PostMapping("/")
    public String greetingSubmit(@ModelAttribute status stat, Model model, databaseConn objA) {
        model.addAttribute("stat", stat);
        System.out.println(stat.getStat());
        try{
            model.addAttribute("alert", objA.datacon());
        }
        catch (Exception e) {

        }
        return "alerts";
    }
```

For `System.out.println(stat.getStat())` Null is printing to the console. Does anyone know why?

Comment: Have you tried adding a default constructor to your stat class? Also just fyi, the convention for class names is to start with an upper case letter, i.e. stat should be Stat

Comment: @DavidWright Just added a constructor, Didn't seem to change anything unfortunately

Comment: Use `th:object` instead of `th::object` and your object is named `stat` not `status`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 problems with the thymleaf code you have posted:

1. you are using th::object instead of th:object
2. you are using th:object="${status}" instead of th:object="${stat}" => You have added stat in the model in the controller hence you should use stat instead of status.

Answer (score 0):

it seems there is a typo in your code,using `th:object="${status}"` instead of `th:object="${status}"`

```
<form action="#" th:action="@{/}" th::object="${status}" method="post">
      <input type="text" th:field="*{stat}"/>
      <br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `model.addattribute("stat",new Status());` to `model.addattribute("status",new Status());`
change `th::object="${status}"` to `th:object="${status}"`